# How to apply patch in wildfly

Tags: wildfly, patch

I am currently running my application in wildfly-26.1.2.Final version, if I need to update the wildfly version to wildfly-26.1.3.Final, what is the recommended approach. I am not seeing any patch zips available in the http://wildfly.org/downloads/ page.

Patching approach recommendation in wildfly

Answer (score 0):

WildFly does not supply any kind of patches to apply on a current installation.

If you need to update your server, you have to download the new version and migrate your configuration and content. Generally speaking, even more with such a micro update from 26.1.2 to 26.1.3, you should be able to copy your configuration directory and use it on your new instance. A summary of the WildFly release cadence can be found here: https://www.wildfly.org/news/2023/05/11/WildFly-Roadmap/

Sometimes, those migrations are not straightforward, for example, if you are migrating with a gap of several major releases in between. There is a migration tool that can help in those cases, see https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration

To avoid those caveats, the best approach is to try to follow the latest versions and not lag behind them too much; you will not only avoid migration issues for the future but also you will run with the latest CVEs applied on your server and available for your applications.

In case you need patches to keep a stable product line on your server, you should be looking at Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform
(JBoss EAP) which is based on WildFly community releases with added commercial support and patch releases through a longer lifecycle.